# maven email plugin

Tags: email, maven, maven-plugin

After performing a '`mvn deploy`' or '`mvn release`', I want to send email to users in a mailing list ?

Is there any maven plugin which does this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send out email notification for Maven build](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243326/how-to-send-out-email-notification-for-maven-build)?

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend to do this only in case of mvn release:prepare release:perform and use the [maven-changes-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-changes-plugin/) which exactly handles such things.